# Define $\mathscr A^\lambda := \{A \cup S : A \in \mathscr A, S \subset \Omega$ with $\lambda^*(S) = 0\}$. Show that this set is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega, \mathscr A, \lambda)$ be a measure space. Define
>
> $\mathscr A^\lambda := \{A \cup S : A \in \mathscr A, S \subset \Omega$ with $\lambda^*(S) = 0\}$.
>
> Show that this set is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I already proved that $\emptyset, \Omega$ and  $\bigcup_{k =1}^\infty (A_k \cup S_k) \in \mathscr A^\lambda$, but I don't see how to show $\Omega \setminus (A \cup S) \in \mathscr A^\lambda$.

I started with

$\Omega \setminus (A \cup S) = \Omega \setminus A \cup \Omega \setminus S$.

Obviously, we know that $\Omega \setminus A \in \mathscr A$ and $\Omega \setminus S \subset \Omega$, but it's left to show that

$\lambda^*(\Omega \setminus S) = 0$ (which is the outer measure, of course).

Comment: is this true? I think you need $S\subseteq A$, in which case $\mathscr A^\lambda$ is just the completion of $\lambda $.